# Show that P(Y = y | Z = 1) = P(Y = y) for y = 1, 3, 7

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

So i have the following PMF for (Z, Y):

|  | Y = 1 | Y = 3 | Y = 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z = 0 | 0.20 | 0.07 | 0.10 |
| Z = 1 | 0.09 | 0.05 | 0.11 |
| Z = 2 | 0.07 | 0.08 | 0.23 |

And i have to show that P(Y = y | Z = 1) = P(Y = y) for y = 1, 3, 7.

I remember having looked at it before, but now when i look back at it i'm completely lost and out of ideas, i can't remember how i solved or what i need to do to solve it now. I hope somebody can help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? For example, what is $P(Y=1 \mid Z=1)$ (a conditional probability)?  What is $P(Y=1)$ (a marginal probability)?

Comment: I am pretty sure about that P(Y = 1 |  Z = 1) = 0.09 and also that P(Y = y | Z = 1) =  P(Y = 1 |  Z = 1) +  P(Y = 3 |  Z = 1) +  P(Y = 7 |  Z = 1) for y = 1, 3, 7 which then would give me P(Y = y | Z = 1) = 0.09 + 0.05 + 0.11 = 0.25 I also think that P(Y = y) = 0.36 is a marginal probability and it has its marginal probability function of course, while the other one is a conditional probability and has the conditional probability function that i provided.

Comment: $0.09$ is the joint probability $P(Y=1 , Z=1)$.  To find the conditional probability $P(Y=1 \mid Z=1)$ you need to divide the joint probability by $P(Z=1)=0.09 + 0.05 + 0.11=0.25$ you calculated trying to find something else.  You should revise joint, conditional and marginal probabilities

Comment: Okay well, one of the things that i have looked at is using the conditional probability of A given B which is defined as P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B), when P(B) > 0.

Comment: Indeed - which is why $P(Y=1 \mid Z=1)=\dfrac{P(Y=1 , Z=1)}{P(Z=1)}$, where both "$,$" and "$\cap$" mean "*and*"

Comment: Okay i can then imagine that we just do that for y = 1, 3, 7 and add the three results together to get P(Y = y | Z = 1)

Comment: $y$ can be $1$ or $3$ or $7$.  So asking for $P(Y=y \mid Z=1)$ is asking for three numbers $P(Y=1 \mid Z=1)$ and $P(Y=3 \mid Z=1)$ and $P(Y=7 \mid Z=1)$.  You do not need to add them up, but if you do then you should get $1$.  Similarly asking for $P(Y=y )$ is asking for three numbers $P(Y=1)$ and $P(Y=3 )$ and $P(Y=7 )$.  Again you do not need to add them up, but if you do then you should again get $1$.

Comment: Okay i can see that i would just get 1 by adding them together.   When you ask for $P(Y = y | Z = 1)$ for $y = 1, 2, 3$ you just ask for the three numbers $0.09$, $0.05$ and $0.11$ is that not right?

Comment: No - the three numbers $0.09$, $0.05$ and $0.11$ are each a joint probability and you are looking for the conditional probabilities

Comment: Okay i keep getting lost, but if we simply look at let's say $\frac{P(Y = 1 | Z = 1)}{P(Z = 1)}$ would that not give us the result $\frac{0.09}{0.25} = 0.36$ or am i just again confusing my joint and conditional probabilities.

Comment: Your notation is still confused, but $P(Y=1 \mid Z=1)=\dfrac{P(Y=1 , Z=1)}{P(Z=1)}=\dfrac{0.09}{0.25} = 0.36$ would be correct.  You now need to compare this to $P(Y=1)$

Comment: Well i assume that $P(Y = 1) = 0.20 + 0.09 + 0.07 = 0.36$ which then would be the same as P(Y = 1 | Z = 1).

Comment: Yes.  Then so something similar to show $P(Y=3 \mid Z=1) =P(Y=3)$ and to show $P(Y=7 \mid Z=1) =P(Y=7)$.  With all three results you will have shown $P(Y=y \mid Z=1) =P(Y=y)$  for $y=1,3,7$

Comment: Okay i get it now and thank you for helping me out.